# Why should the Yoni (Potruding part of Shiva Lingam) always face North?

Tags: shiva, shaivism, shiva-lingam, explanation

I've noticed and understood that, wherever the Shiva Lingam is, the Yoni of the Shiva Lingam should always face North?

I have two Questions:

1. I've seen certain temples in India where Shiva lingas are in a single row but their Yoni directions are opposite. What might be the actual reason?
2. Is there any reference from our Scriptures or Puranas on why the Yoni must always face the North direction?